# Can the alter be replaced with commute in the following Clojure code?

Tags: concurrency, clojure

```
(def alice-height
  (ref 3))

(def right-hand-bites
  (ref 10))

(defn eat-from-right-hand []
  (dosync
    (when (pos? @right-hand-bites)
      (alter right-hand-bites dec)
      (alter alice-height #(+ % 24)))))
```

This code is from the book Living Clojure. In the book, the author also gave an example with **alter** replaced by **commute**. I'm wondering with the `pos?` test at the beginning, can we really do this replacement?

Answer (score 1):

No, replacing `alter` with `commute` when decrementing `right-hand-bites` is not correct.

The intention of the conditional is apparently to prevent `right-hand-bites` from becoming negative. The decrement is only valid under the assumption that `right-hand-bites` won’t change until the end of the transaction. While, like `alter`, `commute` has its own snapshot view of the ref world, it will re-read and re-apply the commute function to the ref *at commit time*, and that would be a mistake in this program.

So, with `commute` it is possible to commit a negative value to `right-hand-bites`.

Either stick with `alter`, or use [`ensure`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/ensure) instead of `@` (though that makes the whole commute exercise rather pointless).

Comment: Interesting little fact: not only is `ensure` beside the point here, it is also prone to (catastrophic) livelock, and I can actually easily reproduce this using your code snippet. See [CLJ-2301](https://clojure.atlassian.net/projects/CLJ/issues/CLJ-2301).

Comment: I think whether or not this matters boils down to the read in the conditional `(when (pos? @right-hand-bites) ...)`. That `deref` on `right-hand-bites` is _not_ inside a `commute` and should be subject to snapshot consistency before a commit. So, if the conditional sees a positive `right-hand-bites` during the read, it should be guaranteed a consistent value before commit. This would change if the conditional were inside of the commute.

Comment: @A.Webb Ref reads cannot detect modification at commit time – for that you need `ensure`. Here again is the crux of the problem: `commute` re-reads the _current value_ of the ref (the one outside the snapshot!) during commit (= still inside the transaction), and then reapplies the commute function _unconditionally_. This is where it becomes a check-then-act bug. Try it for yourself in the REPL, it’s not too difficult to verify.